# Balls in boxes - proof correction

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

I have been thinking about the following problem:

How many ways can $50$ different balls be placed into $50$ different sized boxes if exactly $2$ boxes have to remain empty?

My approach was the following:

> There are two possible cases which satisfy the conditions:
>
> - There are $2$ boxes with $2$ balls and $46$ boxes with $1$ ball;
> - There is $1$ box with $3$ balls and $47$ boxes with $1$ ball.

> In the first case, you can choose the $2$ empty boxes first ($\binom{50}{2}$ possibilities), then you can choose the boxes which have $2$ balls in them ($\binom{48}{2}$ possibilities). After that, you can choose $2$ balls which are placed in the bigger box chosen in the previous step ($\binom{50}{2}$ possibilities), then $2$ balls which are placed in the smaller box ($\binom{48}{2}$ possibilities). Finally, there are only $46$ balls left that have to be placed in the $46$ boxes remained, $1$ ball in each of them ($46!$ possibilities). Totally, there are $\binom{50}{2}* \binom{48}{2}* \binom{50}{2}* \binom{48}{2}* 46!$ possibilities.

> In the second case, following a similar logic, there are $\binom{50}{2}* 48* \binom{50}{3}* 47!$ possibilities totally. The final answer to the question can be given adding these two numbers.

However, using the classic inclusion-exclusion formula, the following number of possibilities arise: $\binom{50}{2}* \sum_{k=0}^{48} (-1)^k \binom{48}{k} * (48-k)^{50}$.

I am quite sure that the number derived from the inclusion-exclusion formula is correct, however, I haven't got any clue what is wrong with my first solution.

I would appreciate any help or explanation why my first solution is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct.

You can apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion and that leads to the same answer.

Using P.I.E, ${50 \choose 2} \times  \sum \limits_{i=0}^{48} {(-1)^i} {48 \choose i} (48-i)^{50}$

Another way to do it will be to choose $2$ empty boxes out of $50$ and then use Stirling Number of the second kind to make $48$ non-empty heaps from $50$ balls and then permute the heaps as we have distinct boxes. That again leads to the same answer.

$S2(50,48) \times 48! \times {50 \choose 2}$

Here is the answer when you calculate any of the above $3$ expressions using Mathematica - $10804606609908677549993379050994509131965157167373221888000000000000000$

Comment: The Stirling numbers didn't come to my mind, it is a nice observation, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[Both solutions seem to be the same.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Binomial%5B50%2C2%5D+*+Binomial%5B48%2C2%5D%29%5E2+*+46%21+%2B+Binomial%5B50%2C2%5D+*+48+*+Binomial%5B50%2C3%5D+*+47%21+-+Binomial%5B50%2C2%5D+*+Sum%5B%28-1%29%5Ek+*+Binomial%5B48%2Ck%5D+*+%2848+-+k%29%5E%2850%29%2C+k%2C+0%2C+48%5D)

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot a multiplicative factor when I checked my solution and the one given by P.I.E.